# How to get U-boot to automatically load from FAT partition

Tags: linux, partition, u-boot, freertos, fat

I have an NXP board with U-boot and Linux on it. On start up, if I don't type anything, the U-boot will automatically start Linux using a linux image. Everything is on my SD card which is plugged into the board.

The SD card has a FAT partition on it that contains a binary file with a FreeRTOS program. I can run it by doing the following:
 1. turn on the board and immediately type anything on the keyboard to get into U-boot
 2. type `fatload mmc 0:1 0x7F8000 hello_world.bin`
 3. type `dcache flush` and then `bootaux 0x7F8000`

I need U-boot to automatically start the FreeRTOS binary file, and not the Linux image. How can I accomplish this? Can I make some kind of startup U-boot script that does these commands on startup? Thanks.

Comment: Your question indicates no research on your part other than some casual tinkering with your board.  The "U" in U-Boot stands for "Universal".  U-Boot tries to make anything possible, so of course it can *"automatically start the FreeRTOS binary file"*.  Study the U-Boot documentation.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know more about u-boot environment variables i suggest you do:

```
u-boot> printenv
```

this command print all env variables on screen. And look at variables description mentioned in  [U-Boot Environment Variables](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootEnvVariables)

Variable bootcmd is most important to understanding. Nothing is really hard and info is out there for you.

Probably the change you would make is

```
u-boot> setenv load_firmware 'fatload mmc 0:1 0x7F8000 hello_world.bin; dcache flush; bootaux 0x7F8000'
u-boot> setenv bootcmd load_firmware
```

then

```
u-boot> saveenv; reboot
```

to save changes and reboot.

Hope this help.